# What was Alexander Selkirk's "flip-can"?

Tags: meaning

Does anyone know what a "flip-can" is in this particular context?

In the [Wikipedia article for Alexander Selkirk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Selkirk) (one of the sources of inspiration for the Robinson Crusoe story), it says:

> In 1825, during John Howell's research of Alexander Selkirk's biography, his "flip-can" was in the possession of his great-grand-nephew John Selkirk...

I've had no luck with Google finding a definition for "flip-can," nor from an online copy of Howell's book.

Comment: Turns out it was a simple [google](http://woodsrunnersdiary.blogspot.com/2010/07/18th-century-flip-can.html) away.

Comment: ... But a valid question, as not in the regular dictionaries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But [*flip* is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flip) (see noun 1). However, it's true that's still probably not a connection easily made.

Answer (score 6):

A 'flip-can' is a sort of jug that's meant to hold flip. *Flip* was once a slang term for "a mixture of beer and spirit sweetened with sugar and heated with a hot iron" (*[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/jcz5bmy)*). This sense of the word goes back to the 17th-century, which fits with the time of Selkirk's life.

This is very likely the intended use in your context. The section "Life of Alexander Selkirk" in *[Chambers's Miscellany of Instructive & Entertaining Tracts](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Chambers_s_miscellany_of_instructive_ent/MzUCAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)* (1871) says:

> The house in which Selkirk lived during his last residence at Largo has recently been pulled down and rebuilt; it is still possessed and occupied by descendants of his brother John. His chest and his cocoa-nut shell cup are now in the Museum of the Society of Antiquaries, Edinburgh. His flip-can exists in the possession of another relation; and his gun is the property of S. R. Lumsdaine, Esq., of Lathallan, near Largo. The flip-can,' says Mr Howell, 'holds about a Scottish pint [two quarts], and is made of brown stoneware, glazed. On it is the following inscription and posy-sailors being in all ages notoriously addicted to inscribing rhymes on such articles:
>
> > "Alexander Selkirk, this is my one.
> > When you take me on board of ship,
> > **Pray fill me full with punch or flip**."
>
> The handle of the jug is gone; its mouth is broken in two places; and a crack in the stoneware is patched with pitch, probably put on by Selkirk's own hands.

Answer (score 2):

Adding some research . . .

A flip-can is a vessel for holding flip, an ale fancied by sailors.

Author [John Howell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Howell_(polyartist)), in his 1829 book [*The Life and Adventures of Alexander Selkirk; Containing the Real Incidents upon Which the Romance of Robinson Crusoe Is Founded: In Which Also the Events of His Life, Drawn from Authentic Sources, Are Traced from His Birth, in 1676, Till His Death, in 1723*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_DSARmYz3DkYC/page/n147/mode/2up?q=flip), writes of Selkirk’s 1703* flip-can:

> But by far the most interesting relic is his flip-can, in possession
> of his great-grand-nephew, John Selcraig. It holds about a Scottish
> pint, and is made of brown stoneware glazed: it resembles a common
> porter-jug as used at the present day. On it is the following
> inscription and posey [*sic*], as, in former times, every thing belonging to a
> sailor that would admit of it had its rhyme:—
>
> <sub>“Alexander Selkirk, this is my
> one.</sub>
>        <sub>___</sub>
>     
>   <sub>When you me take on board of ship,</sub>
>     
>   <sub>Pray fill me full with punch or flip.</sub>
>   
>     <sub>Fulham.”</sub>

[Here is a similar vessel (c. 1675–6)](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/671537), from the [Fulham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fulham_Pottery) factory, the maker of Selkirk's flip-can (as marked at the end of the poem).*

[image: bottle with a thistle medallion]

As for the flip . . .

The OED traces flip back to 1695 ([though earlier examples as *flipp* can be found](https://archive.org/details/bim_early-english-books-1641-1700_the-scowrers-a-comedy-_shadwell-thomas_1691/page/n15/mode/2up?q=%22flipp%22)).

> **flip** *noun<sup>1</sup>*
> **2.** A mixture of beer and spirit sweetened with sugar and heated with a hot iron. (Cf. **egg flip** *n.*)
>  <sub>[earliest
> attestation]</sub>
>  <sub>**1695** Thus we live at Sea; eat Bisket,
> and drink Flip.  W. Congreve, *Love for Love* iii. i. 54</sub>
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

You can see the attestation’s full passage (including “toss a can”—to have a drink) in [*Love for Love*](https://archive.org/details/loveforlovecomed00cong/page/54/mode/2up?q=%22Thus+we+live+at+Sea%3B+eat+Bisket%2C+and+drink+Flip.%22).

---

*<sub>See: [*English Pottery and Porcelain.*](https://archive.org/details/englishpotterypo00downuoft/englishpotterypo00downuoft/page/n7/mode/2up?q=%22flip-can%22) (Edward A. Downman, 1904)</sub>

<sub>Note: [It was said, in 1911](https://archive.org/details/middlesexhistory02univuoft/page/144/mode/2up?q=%22Pray+fill+me+full+of+punch+or+flipp%22), that Selkirk’s flip-can exists in a private collection.</sub>